# AWS JS SDK: Weird behavior GetBucketLifecycleConfiguration after adding rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I found a really weird bug on aws js sdk.

If I try to delete/add LifecycleRules in my s3Bucket (using putBucketLifecycleConfiguration) and fetch theses rules just after this call using getBucketLifecycleConfiguration I can receive more or less rules than that I've put with putBucketLifecycleConfiguration.

If I keep calling getBucketLifecycleConfiguration I will continue to receive more or less rules that I've put, it seems to be a random behavior...

Do you know if it's a known bug or the reason of this behavior?

NOTE: It seems it has the same behavior with `aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration` AND also in the AWS Management Console.
Maybe we have to wait a moment for AWS servers to replicate the data on all servers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the normal behavior of aws, look at this link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html

```
Propagation delay

When you add an S3 Lifecycle configuration to a bucket, there is  
 usually some lag before a new or updated Lifecycle configuration is  
 fully propagated to all the Amazon S3 systems. Expect a delay of a  
 few minutes before the configuration fully takes effect.
This delay can also occur when you delete an S3 Lifecycle configuration.
```